# how do you put text on different lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My df looks like this:

```
 Product       Day      Month Total
Web Server, Applicatiion Server, Database Server, Middle Tier Tue 2015-01-01  10
Web Server, Application Server, Database Server, Middle Tier  Wed 2015-01-01    6
Web Server, Application Server, Database Server, Middle Tier  Wed 2015-02-01    6
```

I need to create a heat map in ggplot2 where I need to insert Product name as geom_text.

I have this so far:

```
ggplot(cal, aes(x=Month, y=Day, fill=Total)) +
   geom_tile() +
   scale_fill_gradient2(high="red",mid="green",low="yellow", 
       na.value="white", midpoint=mean(cal$Total, na.rm=T))+scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"), breaks = date_breaks("month"))+
       geom_text(aes(label=Product))
```

What happens is since there are multiple Product names separated by comma, when I do geom_text (aes(label=Product)), text is written on top of each other.

Is it possible put each Product name on different lines?

Comment: ggplot2 can't do automatic linebreaks for you. Have you tried adding `\n` after `,` in your `Product` names?

Comment: @Roland, I just tried your recommendation inserting \n after the comma in my data frame, still the same. Text are written on top of each other.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just add `"\n"` to your "Product" labels wherever you need a line break:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  label=c("bla \n foo", "first line \n second line"),
  x = c(1, 2), y =c(1,2))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label)) + geom_text()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, it seems to be working. But I still see text on top of each other. How else I can enforce each text to be on the new line?

Comment: `position_dodge` does not work with `geom_text`, so I guess you'll have to shorten your labels and/or reduce the fontsize (`geom_text(size = 4)` or sth like that) to avoid overlap.

Comment: Any way to control spacing between the two lines of text?